# jquery get radiobuttonlist by name dynamically

Tags: jquery

I have two radiobuttonlist and one checkboxlist on the page. Ideally based on the checkbox selected value, I want to enable/disable corresponding radibuttonlist with jquery function.

But some how $("input[name*=" + columnName + "]") always return null. It can not find the radiobuttonlist by its name?

```
    $(function() {
        function checkBoxClicked() {

            var isChecked = $(this).is(":checked");
            var columnName = "rblColumn" + $(this).parent().attr("alt");

            if (isChecked) {
                $("input[name*=" + columnName + "]").removeAttr("disabled");
            } else {
                $("input[name*=" + columnName + "]").attr("disabled", "disabled");

                $("input[name*=" + columnName + "] input").each(function() {
                    $(this).attr("checked", "")
                });

            }

        }

        //intercept any check box click event inside the #list Div
        $(":checkbox").click(checkBoxClicked);
    });




<asp:Panel ID="TestPanel" runat="server">
<asp:CheckBoxList ID = "chkColumn" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
    <asp:ListItem id = "Column1" runat="server" Text="Column 1" Value="1" alt="1" class="HeadColumn" />
    <asp:ListItem id = "Column2" runat="server" Text="Column 2" Value="2" alt="2" class="HeadColumn"/>
</asp:CheckBoxList>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:RadioButtonList ID = "rblColumn1" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Vertical" disabled="disabled">
                <asp:ListItem id="liColumn1p" runat="server" />
                <asp:ListItem id="liColumn1n" runat="server" />
            </asp:RadioButtonList>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:RadioButtonList ID = "rblColumn2" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Vertical" disabled="disabled">
                <asp:ListItem id="liColumn2p" runat="server" />
                <asp:ListItem id="liColumn2n" runat="server" />
            </asp:RadioButtonList>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</asp:Panel>
```

source:

```
<div id="TestPanel">

<table id="chkColumn" border="0">
        <tr>
            <td><span id="Column1" alt="1" class="HeadColumn"><input id="chkColumn_0" type="checkbox" name="chkColumn$0" /><label for="chkColumn_0">Column 1</label></span></td><td><span id="Column2" alt="2" class="HeadColumn"><input id="chkColumn_1" type="checkbox" name="chkColumn$1" /><label for="chkColumn_1">Column 2</label></span></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table id="rblColumn1" class="myRadioButtonList" disabled="disabled" border="0">
        <tr>
            <td><span id="liColumn1p"><input id="rblColumn1_0" type="radio" name="rblColumn1" value="" /></span></td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td><span id="liColumn1n"><input id="rblColumn1_1" type="radio" name="rblColumn1" value="" /></span></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
        </td>
        <td>
            <table id="rblColumn2" class="myRadioButtonList" disabled="disabled" border="0">
        <tr>
            <td><span id="liColumn2p"><input id="rblColumn2_0" type="radio" name="rblColumn2" value="" /></span></td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td><span id="liColumn2n"><input id="rblColumn2_1" type="radio" name="rblColumn2" value="" /></span></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

</div>
```

Comment: Can you post the markup? It's hard to diagnose why a selector doesn't match without seeing what it's not matching :)

Comment: You need to include the **generated** HTML. Ignore all the server side code (ASP.NET, JSF/JSP, whatever), it's irrelevant and invisible for JavaScript/jQuery. Open the page in a webbrowser, rightclick and choose *View Source*. That's the real HTML which  JS/jQuery can see/access. Copypaste it here.

Comment: Your question title states that you want them by ID, but your code is getting them by name. Does the `ID` of the `asp:RadioButtonList` translate to `name` attributes for the radio buttons?

Comment: @Cindy - I rolled your question back since your last edit effectively obliterated the question. Was there another update you wanted to do?

Comment: @Patrick - thanks for rolling question back. I am trying to post the source for this.

Comment: <table id="rblColumn1" class="myRadioButtonList" disabled="disabled" border="0">
  <tr>
   <td><span id="liColumn1p"><input id="rblColumn1_0" type="radio" name="rblColumn1" value="" /></span></td>
  </tr><tr>
   <td><span id="liColumn1n"><input id="rblColumn1_1" type="radio" name="rblColumn1" value="" /></span></td>
  </tr>
 </table>

Comment: @Cindy - You posted the HTML, but without indenting it at least 4 spaces, it won't be formatted, and (in the case of HTML) likely won't show up at all. I've edited your question to format the code. I also posted a solution below, which I believe solves the issue.

Comment: <table id="rblColumn2" class="myRadioButtonList" disabled="disabled" border="0">
  <tr>
   <td><span id="liColumn2p"><input id="rblColumn2_0" type="radio" name="rblColumn2" value="" /></span></td>
  </tr><tr>
   <td><span id="liColumn2n"><input id="rblColumn2_1" type="radio" name="rblColumn2" value="" /></span></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
        </td>
    </tr>

Comment: @Cindy - I'll post the code from your comment for you. FYI, to indent code, just paste it like you did, then select it and either click the "Code Sample" button at the top of the editor (the 101010 button), or do `CTRL + k`.

Comment: @Cindy - Just update your question by pasting the code at the very bottom, and I'll format it for you if needed.

Comment: @Patrick, I have two radiobuttonlists: rblColumn1 and rblColumn2 instead of rblColumn_1 in your answer. The source actually says: "rblColumn1" is a table. Now I am trying: $("table[name*=" + columnName + "]").removeAttr("disabled"); But still not working.

Comment: I use alert and verify that columnName here is "rblColumn1"

Comment: @Cindy - I was wrong. I was still stuck on the ID, when you want the name. Seems like your code should be working. I'll take another look.

Comment: @Cindy - Your code appears to be working here: http://jsfiddle.net/jxKAp/ I copied and pasted the exact code, and clicking the checkboxes enables and disables the radio buttons.

Comment: @Cindy - ...and you don't want to use `table[name*=...` since the `table` elements don't have `name` attributes. Only `ID` attributes. The link I posted in the comment above uses the original version with `input[name*=...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it. I added cssclass to each radiobutonlist and find it by id:

$(".myRadioButtonList[id*=" + columnName + "]").removeAttr("disabled");

This is working now. Thanks, Patrick. You remind me about id/name misuse.

Comment: Glad you got it working. There is one other error in the code. I'll post an answer so you can see it fully formatted.

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me (jQuery):

```
$('[name*="' + columnName + '"]');
```